# Run xgboost algorithm gives compilation error

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I am trying to run XGBoost Classifier on my training and testing dataset

here is my code

```
xgboost.fit(x_train, y_train, early_stopping_rounds=25, eval_metric = "auc", eval_set=[x_test, y_test], verbose= True)
```

I am getting this error

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-183-5e6325da9ecc> in <module>
      1 xgboost = XGBClassifier()
----> 2 xgboost.fit(x_train, y_train, early_stopping_rounds=25, eval_metric = "auc", eval_set=[x_test, y_test], verbose= True)

c:\python39\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, callbacks)
    800             else:
    801                 assert len(sample_weight_eval_set) == len(eval_set)
--> 802             evals = list(
    803                 DMatrix(eval_set[i][0],
    804                         label=self._le.transform(eval_set[i][1]),

c:\python39\lib\site-packages\xgboost\sklearn.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    801                 assert len(sample_weight_eval_set) == len(eval_set)
    802             evals = list(
--> 803                 DMatrix(eval_set[i][0],
    804                         label=self._le.transform(eval_set[i][1]),
    805                         missing=self.missing, weight=sample_weight_eval_set[i],

c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2904             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2905                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2906             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2907             if is_integer(indexer):
   2908                 indexer = [indexer]

c:\python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 0
```

I am new in this field so I could not found the cause of the problem, can anyone please help

Comment: What is the Interval or your target classes? If it is [1, C], try to make it [0, C-1]